# What does >filename.txt do in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I was reviewing one shell code and I found this command written between other shell code

```
>filename.txt
```

I don't know what this command does, so I tried it on my desktop.  I made one shell script and I wrote this command inside my shell script and when I ran that, I found that it doesn't do anything. 
What does this  >myfile.txt  do??

Comment: Actually it was just >filename.txt  there was nothing before '>' sign

Comment: It's to clear the file.  The keyword is "nothing".  See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have written with **nothing** preceding the redirect symbol `>`:

```
>filename.txt
```

is to literally *redirect* **nothing** into `filename.txt`. 
This is commonly done to clear/erase the contents of a text file. 
If `filename.txt` does not already exist, it will be created.

Answer (score 4):

`> file` alone is a redirection without a redirected command. Depending on the shell, it is:

- a syntax error (Thompson shell, `csh`, `tcsh`, `fish`)
- it runs the *null command* (`zsh`, see `info zsh NULLCMD`) with its output redirected to `file`.
- it performs the redirection (here opens the file for writing with truncation (`O_TRUNC`), with `O_CREAT`, possibly with `O_EXCL` if the `noclobber` option is set), but then closes the corresponding file descriptor without doing anything since no command was provided (Bourne-like shells (except `zsh` unless in `sh`/`ksh` emulation), `rc`-like shells).

Most likely that code was written for shells in the third category, and the intention was to either truncate the file or create it with an empty content.

More portable ways to do that would be to redirect a command that produces no output:

```
printf '' > file

[ . ] > file

true > file # printf, [ and true are builtins in many shells

eval > file # eval is built-in in all shells but note that in POSIX ones, that
            # causes the shell to exit if the file can't be opened. Bourne-like
            # shells also have a ":" builtin with the same side-effect.
```

To force the truncation even when the `noclobber` option is on:

```
true >! file # csh (where noclobber comes from), tcsh, zsh
true >| file # ksh/POSIX (and zsh)
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `> myfile.txt` will just create a file or clear the file content, if any.

This command is also to attribute something to a .txt file, if there is a command before. For example, you want to create a file with the content of a folder so you can do `ls -1 > myfile.txt`. This will create a file with the names of your files and directories by line.

You also can use it as a logfile of your script, so instead of show the output in the screen this command save the output in a file.

Comment: There was no command written before '>'  symbol so it was not output redirection

Comment: Then the command `> myfile.txt` will just create a file or clear the file content, if any.

Comment: You should add this to your answer. OP does not ask what `ls -1 > filename.txt` is supposed to do, but what `> filename.txt` (alone) is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command like filename.txt. It's only an text file named as filename.

As you asked in the title

> What does >filename.txt does in shell script

">" is used for redirecting the output of the command into the text file. for example if you run the below command in the terminal

```
ifconfig > filename.txt
```

then the output of command ifconfig will not display in the terminal. but a new file will create on your working directory or overwrite if the same file is present there. You can read the output of the command from the file filename.txt.

Comment: The appearance of the filename was a formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

`script.sh > file.txt` overwrites the file with the output of the script.
Whereas, `script.sh >> file.txt` appends text to the end of the file.

You can redirect any output from any program on the command line to a file like this. However, this only redirects STDOUT, if you want errors in the file, too, use something like `script.sh > file.txt 2>&1`. This sends STDERR to STDOUT, which is being written to a file.

Comment: No there was no command written before '>' symbol it was just >filename.txt so it can not be considered as output redirection of any command to filename.txt

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's stores the output of that command. E.g. with

```
ls -ltr > command.txt
```

the output of `ls -ltr` will be stored in `command.txt`.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that the OP in several comments stated that there is no command before the `>` redirection operator. So, the effect would be to simply truncate the file (if the shell's syntax allows this). You may want to edit your post to make it more targeted at the OPs question, and also make the difference between your answer and [similar existing answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353154/377345) to this question clearer.